# redirect doesn't work in the Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, redirect, model-view-controller, controller

Hhere is a registration field, after registration it should go to the menu page, but it goes to main

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class SignInPageController {

    private UserDao userDao;
@Autowired
    public SignInPageController(UserDao userDao){this.userDao = userDao;}

@GetMapping("/menu")
    public String mainMenuPage(){
        return "main/menu";
    }
@GetMapping("/signup")
    public String signUpPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("newuser", new User());
        return "main/signup";
    }
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public String signUp(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                             @RequestParam("password") String password,
                             @RequestParam("email") String email,
                             @RequestParam("nativeLanguage") String nativeLanguage){
        User user = new User(name, password, email, nativeLanguage);
        userDao.signUpUser(user);
        return "redirect:/main/menu";
    }
```

can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: I dont really get what's the expected behavior : What are you calling "registration" ? You want the user to go through the signup, then redirect him to the main menu ? Btw why are you returning a String type and not ModelAndView type ? And in my opinion you should avoid using constant written like that in your code, if they are duplicated, it'll be harder to maintain !

Comment: Yes, the expected behavior is to add a user to the database and go to the main menu page. Are you saying that I should pass the model to my mainMenuPage method?

Comment: So have you tried setting up breakpoint in each methods to see where it is landing ?
And yes try changing the return type of "signUp" from String to ModelAndView and return such as  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/main/menu", model);

Comment: But the model is a different matter, first you should make sure your pathing is correct, then we'll check if your redirectAttributes and the data you need are present in each of the methods of your RequestMapping

Comment: I solved the redirect problem by adding a model to the controller method (as well as correcting an error on the html view - the path of the action parameter in the form was incorrectly specified). Thank you very much, can you mark your comment as an answer?)

Comment: Great ! glad to hear that, i'll post the comment as an answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I was saying in the comments :

You should be returning a `ModelAndView` type from your controller's method, with a return such as :

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/main/menu", model);
```

As you mentionned you also encoutered an issue with a incorrect redirection, try to use defined CONSTANTS to avoid typos :)

If you're new to Spring, make sure to look into `RedirectAttributes`, adding `flashAttributes`, and check the documentation on Baeldung it is really complete.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `@Controller` Spring annotation on your `SignInPageController` class.

So you should get something like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
// And your other imports...

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class SignInPageController {

    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public SignInPageController(UserDao userDao){this.userDao = userDao;}

    @GetMapping("/menu")
    public String mainMenuPage(){
        return "main/menu";
    }

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String signUpPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("newuser", new User());
        return "main/signup";
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String signUp(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                             @RequestParam("password") String password,
                             @RequestParam("email") String email,
                             @RequestParam("nativeLanguage") String nativeLanguage){
        User user = new User(name, password, email, nativeLanguage);
        userDao.signUpUser(user);
        return "redirect:/main/menu";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is just a typo. my code contains this annotation. fixed the issue

Comment: Ah, good to read ;) even better that you managed to fix it yourself!